# What is the inverted sentence for this?

Tags: grammar, sentence-patterns

I arrived on time, as my classmates did, but the lecturer wasn’t there.

Comment: Can you tell us what you understand by _inverted sentence_, or give us an example?

Comment: Rewrite these sentence to make it inverted sentence.

For an example: The crowd cheered loudly as he ran round the stadium.

Answer: Round the stadium he ran as the crowd cheered loudly.

Comment: An inverted sentence is a sentence in a normally subject-first language in which the predicate comes before the subject.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. In your inverted sentence example the subject (_he_) still comes before the (simple) predicate (_ran_). The sentence starts with a prepositional phrase (_round the stadium_). The only prepositional phrase in the sentence you are asking about is _on time_. I suppose you could front this phrase but it produces a very strange sentence.

Comment: Thank you so much!
It also implies this. 
Normal Sentence: The cat jumped up and the mouse ran away. 
Inverted Sentence: Up jumped the cat and away ran the mouse. 
Can you apply this in this sentence? 
I arrived on time, as my classmates did, but the lecturer wasn’t there.
What do you think is the right answer?

Comment: _Up_ in _jumped up_ is an adverb particle. There is no equivalent in your sentence. The only thing that could sensibly be inverted is: _as my classmates did_ >> _as did my classmates_.

Comment: Can you suggest possible answer? I am so sorry to bother but I do appreciate your effort in helping me. Thank you so much!

Comment: As did my classmates, I arrived on time, but the lecturer wasn't there.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

The only sensible inversion in the sentence you quote is in the *'as my classmates did'* clause.

The entry for *as* in *Collins Cobuild English Usage* (p67) includes this explanation:

> When you have just made a statement, you can use **as** as a conjunction
> to indicate that the statement also applies to another person, thing
> or group. After *as* you use 'be', 'have' an auxiliary, or a modal,
> then the subject.
>
> - Edmund Burke liked that term, as did the authors of America's
>   Federalist Papers.

Your sentence rewritten on this basis to invert the subject and auxiliary in the '*as my classmates did'* clause reads:

- I arrived on time, as did my classmates, but the lecturer wasn’t there.